# How to make evancz/url-parser to return rest of path as String?

Tags: parsing, elm

How to make evancz/url-parser to match start of path and return rest of path as String?
For example:

```
s "search" </> string |> format Search
```

does not match if path is something like "search/text/with/slashes"

I expect to get Search with "text/with/slashes" String as payload.

Answer (score 1):

evancz/url-parser seems to handle only segments separated by '/'.
I guess you have to write your own parser.
(here, I integrated with `yourparser` which is your existing parser using url-parser)

```elm
urlParser : Navigation.Parser (Result String String)
urlParser =
  let
    parser : Navigation.Location -> (Result String String)
    parser location =
      Maybe.oneOf
        [ Result.toMaybe (yourparser location)
        , Result.toMaybe (extractSearch location.pathname)
        ]
      |> Result.fromMaybe "parse error"
    extractSearch pathname = 
      if String.startsWith "/search/" pathname
      then Ok (String.dropLeft 8 pathname)
      else Err "failed to extract search string"
  in Navigation.makeParser yourparser
```